# How do you force automatic updates on Home Screen Web App for iOS 12?

Tags: ios, caching, progressive-web-apps, reload

I have a web app that is to be added to the Home Screen on iOS 12.x. Basically I want the app to be reloaded (updated) when the user clicks on the icon, just the way to does in Safari.

This most likely is due to the changes in PWA lifecycle introduced in iOS 12.2, but I am looking for a solution for keeping my users updated to the latest app version.

I have tried many solutions offered in previous similar questions but nothing seems to work. Here is my current solution for Safari:

I have the following cache.manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Version 1.0001

NETWORK:
*
```

I have this in my html file:

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
...
    <script>
        function updateSite(event) {
            //window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        //Check cache for updates
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', updateSite, false);
    </script>
```

This works perfectly with Safari, but it does not do anything for the Home Screen web app.

In Safari, when the cache.manifest file changes Safari automatically loads the new html file.

How can I replicate this behavior for the Home Screen app? 
Or is there any other recommended way so the user has the most recent version of my app?